# Errors occur when updated from Java 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: android

I had projects that were running fine but when I updated from Java 1.6 to 1.7 two of the projects I have ended up getting errors Failed to run com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.AidlProcessor. Check workspace log for detail. and am not sure how to fix these has anyone already found this out.

Comment: Did you change the path of Java from 1.6 to 1.7?

Comment: no they were all still 1.6, i found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261781/aidl-files-not-building-in-eclipse-in-random-projects

Answer (score 0):

remember that Android does not support Java 7. So you should install the java 1.6 along with the 1.7 (if you really need to use 1.7 for something else non Android) and make your eclipse point to your java 1.6